# custom approval workflow, provide approval link via email

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, sharepoint-designer

I'm putting together a custom approval workflow. One of the requirements is to send an email to approvers were they can click a link to either approve or disapprove the item verses browsing to a task form.

ex. The e-mail sent to the approver has all the item information provided in the body of the email. At the bottom of the email content the approver will see a link to "approve" the request. Once the link is click, it will update the item's "status" field to approve.

Does anyone have a good example on how to achieve this using "string builder" in SharePoint designer?

Comment: I think the problem you will find, is that clicking a link in an email wont have a valid FormDigest. SharePoint wont except the action as it cannot be validated (unless you build a custom component)

Comment: Please, did you find an answer to your question, I am facing the same problem. Best Regards,

Comment: Will customize the OOB workflow only impact the site collection you are editing? Will it affect other site collection using the OOB workflow?

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do in SPD is craft a URL to the EditForm of the task I believe.

If you're wanting to do it strictly in email, you'll need to get a tool like [Nintex Workflow](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Pages/default.aspx) that allows for LazyApproval.  This feature, when enabled in the workflow, allows users to simply respond to a workflow notification via email with a configurable list of predefined action words like Yes, No, Approve, Reject, and the workflow continues on.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the real solution would be writing some code (maybe and application page to get the information from the url and perform some actions.
However if you don't use visual studio then you should be able to use the client OM or web services to update a specific item  (bit hacky though)
Are you using 2007 on sp 2010 ?